# Charset issue in a webform

Tags: webforms

We have got a multisite structure with several sites. One of the sites has got a webform, from which client needs to download submissions from time to time. However, when we choose to export to Excel using the default values (delimited text and \t as delimiter format), Turkish characters get corrupted on a Windows. I have got no trouble on Linux, but client uses Windows. I must also mention that this behaviour doesn't occur on another site in the same multisite structure. What could I be missing?

EDIT: We are running Drupal 7.34, Webform 7.x-3.21, PHP 5.2.17, and we are using MS Office 2007. I export to Excel using /node/%nid/webform-results/download. I have also tried exporting the Webform to another site on the same multisite structure (hence the same PHP version) and verified it works fine there.
Regards,

Comment: In windows opening the file in notepad the values getting corrupted rite? and if you can provide what is the file extension you use it will be more easy to track your issue.

Comment: I opened them both in notepad++, one of them (the working one) looks correct while the other one is filled with NULs. Their file extension is .xls (I've tried with .csv too)

Comment: How do you export to Excel? What version of Drupal? What version of MS Windows?  What version of PHP? There a too little information here to make this answerable (I am not going to waste my time on a shot in the dark).  If you want value for your bounty, you need to make the question better.

Comment: @FreeRadical you're right, I improved my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 months of dabbling, I managed to solve this by adding some PHP to includes/webform.export.inc:

```
<?php

 if (function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) {
      $user_agent = strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Windows');
      if ($user_agent) {
        $row = mb_convert_encoding($row, 'UTF-16LE', 'ISO-8859-9');
      }
      else {
        $row = mb_convert_encoding($row, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
      }
    }
?>
```

Not sure how to do it for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a fix for your problem, perhaps you should try this on your test environment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2060519

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying but I forgot to mention that we are running 3.x

Comment: you might have to consider updating then to fix your issue.

Comment: That is not possible as we are running PHP 5.2.17 and sysadmins will unlikely agree to upgrade.

Comment: I think this is the file that you should alter (this is where the conversion occurs), maybe you can play around with it on your test environment: http://drupalapi.attiks.com/api/webform/includes!webform.export.inc/function/webform_exporter_delimited%3A%3Aadd_row/7.x-3.x

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning again that this is a multisite structure.